# View hierarchy changed after push a view controller through navigation controller?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, hierarchy, pushviewcontroller

There is problem in view hierarchy. Here is flow of my app.
[image]

When app starts View Controller "A" is Visible. After that storyboard "B" is loaded through "**StoryBoard Reference (Push)**" ,Where another navigation controller is present and Home screen is loaded. On Click of Menu button in Home screen Side panel is visible.

Now When i click on side panel menu items **view Controller "B"** is pushed. This View Controller is Pushed Under Home screen and is not Vsible.

[image]

**Help View contoller** is visible under **Home controller**. I want **Help View Controller** should come on top of **Home controller.**
I dont understand what issue is coming..
Any Help will be appreciated..

Comment: Are you pushing side menu on navigation controller? or presenting it ?

Comment: I am presenting side panel on Navigation controller, after that on menu action specific view controller is pushed.

Comment: Check my answer !!

Answer (score 0):

If you are pushing view controller from side panel shows in image, will never  push because it is not in navigation controller.

the answer depends on how you showing your side menu but from assumptions

what you need to do is to set root view controller or keep reference of navigation controller and push from there

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Side panel is presented on Home Controller. After Debugging i came to know that Help view controller is pushed on navigation controller but it is under Home View Controller.. Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

If you are presenting side menu then it is not on `navigation controller` so you should first `dismiss` this side menu and on the completion of it you should push new view controller (says B or Help). I am writing my code snippet that i am using in my project for demonstration,

```
 - (IBAction)settingClick:(id)sender {



SettingViewController *svc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"settingsScreen"];



[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{


    [self.vc.navigationController.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];


        }];


}
```

Above method push `setting view controller` on current `navigation controller` after dismissing `side menu`

Now important thing is `self.vc` this is the object of `previous viewcontroller` (Home controller in your case i think) on which side menu was presented.

So my `SideMenuViewController` has a property like,

```
 @property (nonatomic,strong) UIViewController *vc;
```

which i am setting with `self` from previous view controller (in your case from Home view controller) something like,

```
    SideMenuViewController *smvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"sideMenu"];



            smvc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
            [self presentViewController:smvc animated:NO completion:^{


                smvc.vc = self;

            }];
```

And i have used `[self.vc.navigationController.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];` i.e. two navigation controller to push because i have two navigation controller in my view hierarchy to push this new view controller.

You can manage that as per your setup that how many navigation controller you have !!

Hope this will help :)

Comment: I have Used this ,but no success.

Comment: . I have also used following approach..
[self performSelector:@selector(pushViewController) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
- (void)pushViewController {
    RGNavigationController *navVC =(RGNavigationController*) self.frostedViewController.contentViewController;
    HelpController *helpVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HelpController"];
    if ([navVC.topViewController isKindOfClass:[HelpController class]]) {
        [self.frostedViewController hideMenuViewController];
        return;
    }
    [navVC pushViewController:helpVC animated:YES];
}

Answer (score 0):

After digging a lot, I found solution for this.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Home" bundle: nil];
RootController *someViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RootController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:someViewController animated:YES];
```

I have set another navigation controller as root ViewController of the window and it worked for me.
Thanks.